# BX or Greenfield

Tags: electrical

I don't know if this is Bx or greenfield? It was attached inside my garage that leads to that outdoor receptacle.

[image: indoor wire --????]

[image: receptacle two plugs]

Should i replace this wire if it is bx regardless that I'm grandfather to play it safe. And if i do replace it  what type of wire metal clad, greenfield, etc. since in cook county il everything is conduit and steel boxes? As Harper indicated that I'm grandfather in; however the receptacle isn't working and I'm planning to replace it with a gfci and an extra duty in-use box with the gfci inside a bigger box. What would you recommend concerning this bx? Thanks again

Comment: Can you trace it to a junction box then open that junction box up and get us a photo of the inside?

Comment: Don't put the GFCI in the outdoor receptacle.  Put the GFCI at the first upstream receptacle *that is indoors*.  That'll save you the cost of an outdoor GFCI.   Any GFCI receptacle can protect all the downstream receptacles via its LOAD terminals.   Don't waste your money chaining a GFCI to another GFCI.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If it was bad the house would have burned down long ago. Don't worry about it. 

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your picture I am sure it's not greenfield. If you kill the power to the box, take the cover off and you may have to unscrew the receptacle. Check to see if there is a copper ground wire to connected to the receptacle. If there is not you have BX if there is it was probably installed with MC. Now as @Harper was pointing out an outdoor receptacle should be protected by a GFCI device or breaker. NEC Article 406(D)(2)(b) says you can protect ungrounded conductors by installing a GFCI device and labeling it "no equipment ground" (comes with the device). This receptacle should also be a non-tamperable design (personal opinion).

So in conclusion you can either replace the receptacle with a GFCI non-tamperable receptacle and install a new in-use weather cover. Or replace install a GFCI upstream and install a new non-tamperable receptacle in the outdoor location with a new in-use weather cover. Or if it's BX you can replace the cabling with a code approved method making sure you receptacle is GFCI protected. Any of these methods should protect you and your family. Also if you decide to remove the BX or just feel like it I would see about recessing it into the wall which would prevent someone or something knocking off the wall (another personal opinion).

Comment: Will take yours and Harper's advice. Will recess it into the wall or place a back box with an in-use cover. Regardless appreciated the insights. Last related question, when can you use MC or greenfield in a house or a garage though the code requires conduit and steel boxes but does make exception to this rule. I noticed in my bathroom the light switch is MC to the cabinet light fixture. So when can you run this and does NEC address this? Again thank you both.

Comment: They do make plastic boxes with KO's or methods to secure MC. The old idea was to insure a ground throughout the system, since the industry has moved to running a ground wire in most systems the hard connection metal to metal has fallen off especially in residential. Just make sure all metal is properly secured to the ground system. I've never had a problem with the AHJ using this method.

Comment: Alot of options---again neophyte with garage. Haper menrioned i have a fee alternatives. One final question and sone with this if you recess it into the aluminum and wood covering behind wouldnt the back of the boc would be showing in an unfinished farage. I assume that would be fine. Right?